# WordNet access using php

Tags: php, wordnet, shell-exec

I tried to access the wordnet dictionary as mentioned in: [Calling wordnet from php (Wordnet class or API for PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332254/calling-wordnet-from-php-wordnet-class-or-api-for-php).
It worked fine through command line. Then I tried to use the php function shell_exec() as below to access the dictionary:

```
<?php 

$output=shell_exec("\Program Files (x86)\WordNet\2.1\bin\wn");
echo $output;
?>
```

This displays the search option like -ant, -hyp, and so on.i.e it worked fine

But when I tried to add the search option in the above command(as below) it did not work:

```
<?php 

$output=shell_exec("\Program Files (x86)\WordNet\2.1\bin\wn star -synsn");
echo $output;
?>
```

or even when I gave space in the command like:

```
$output=shell_exec("\Program Files (x86)\WordNet\2.1\bin\wn   ")
```

it did not work.

Can you please help me what may be the reason for this and any suggestion for the solution?

Comment: The filename does not look valid to me for a windows path. Isn't the drive letter missing?

Comment: @hakre's comment looks like the answer -- try `C:\Program Files...` etc.

Comment: 2)even when i added the drive letter it did not work. the code look like this:$output=shell_exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\WordNet\2.1\bin\wn home -synsn");

Answer (score 1):

ok i got the solution now.the problem was because of the spaces between the command.So i handled them as below:

```
$cmd = '"C:/Program Files (x86)/WordNet/2.1/bin/wn" "home" "-synsn"';
$output=shell_exec($cmd);
```

thanks to all who responded to my query